# Using easy custom routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

It's my first time dealing with routes on ASP.Net Mvc and I'm trying to do something like StackOverflow does with it's questions.

I have my controller called `News` it haves his actions like `News/`, `News/Create`, `News/Edit/1` etc. I want to add this custom route `News/1` that will return the visualization of the news itself, instead of the grid that the default index `News/` shows.

These are my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ViewNews",
    url: "{controller}/News/{newsId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { newsId = @"\d+" }
);
```

The first ones is the default route, the second one is what I tried for now, following [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC). But it just gives me this error(on this url `News/1`):

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.

I want to know what I'm doing wrong once it doesn't even reach the Action. If I try `News/` it works nice.

I have done this with my action:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        var news = _newsService.GetView((int)id);

        if (news != null)
        {
            return View("News", news);
        }
        else 
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

It would be nice if somebody could tell how to do like SO: `News/1/news-title-here`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `News/` matches the default routing.

You're probably looking for this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ViewNews",
    url: "News/{newsId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { newsId = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Note that you should put the most important route first, because it will be processed in that order. This route will match any url starting with `News` and having a newsId according to your constraint and route it to the `Index` action of the `News` controller.

On a side note: `{newsId}` refers to the parameter with the same name in the action. So your setup for your index should be something like this:

```
public class NewsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int newsId)
    {
    }
}
```

If you'd wish to accept a dummy parameter like `News/1/news-title-here` you could use the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ViewNews",
    url: "News/{newsId}/{customTitle}",
    defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Index",
                    customTitle = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { newsId = @"\d+" }
);
```

Comment: Well, I did not thought that this will make any difference. I'll try.

Comment: Yeah, I'd realized that I should change the action parameter to `newsId`. It worked dude, thank you.

Comment: You know how can I use my url like `News/1/news-title-here` ? If is not too much to ask your time.

Comment: Ouch, so easy. Thank you again dude! I have to read and learn more of this topic!